# How do i solve type 'subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Tab2Page': http, navCtrl

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, subscribe

I'm new to ionic and Angular stuffs. I've been watching a tutorial that is creating an app that's supposed to to get posts from Reddit...but I've been facing a series of errors and I really don't understand them. Here's my code of Tab2Page.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-tab2',
 templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {
http: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient) {
 return this.http.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10')
   .subscribe ((response: any) => {
     this.http = response.data.children;
}
}
```

So do you guys see what the problem is? I'ld really appreciate it if I can get help soon enough. I'm using the app as a project and I have to present it on Wednesday, next week. Thanks☺

Comment: 3 things I could notice: 1) Is NavController an injectable service/component? if not, you cannot inject it in constructor. 2) does your response contain .data and .data.children ? if not, it could generate errors too. 3) also, pls make sure the services are added as providers either in your app module or component under providers: [ NavController ]. could you please provide the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

```
export class Tab2Page {
http: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient) {
```

You have two different declarations of a property named `http`, one is an instance of the `HttpClient`, and one is supposed to store the results of an API call. You need to rename one of them.

Then, if you get errors, please share the full error messages. They really do help. Usually.